# array partition function

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a function that gets an array of `int` and its size:

```
void partition(int data[], int size)
```

The first element of the array is assigned to a variable named `val`, and the function needs to partition the array such that elements to the left of `val` are smaller than `val`, and elements to the right are greater.

For example,

- if the array is : `5 2 10 4 1 12 7` (`val` becomes `5`)
- The output should be `2 4 1 5 10 12 7`

The order doesn't matter so `1 2 4 5 12 7 10` is also valid output

So I wrote this code:

```
void partition(int data[], int size)
{
    int val = data[0];
    int i = 0, j = size - 1;//array indices
    while (i != j)
    {
        while (data[i] < val)
            i++;
        while (data[j] > val)
                j--;
        swapInArray(data, i, j);
    }
}
```

which works fine unless it gets an array with elements equivalent to `val`.

For example : `7 8 5 176 18 19 7 12 44`

Comment: `while (data[i] <= val)` instead of `while (data[i] < val)` should do it.

Comment: it doesn't help, and moreover when changed it now program crashes even with input it worked before the change

Comment: The other problem was use of `while (i != j)` instead of `while (i < j)`.

Comment: still not working, giving the func int data[8] = { 5, 2, 10, 4, 1, 12, 5, 7 }; and it prints 5 2 5 4 12 1 10 7

Comment: I hope you've got it working by now. Just a supplementary comment - I assume this is part of an exercise towards creating a Quicksort algorithm (or something similar) so for learning it's ok, but in the real world a quality piece of code should make best use of the Standard Library. Use std::array instead of raw C-style arrays; and use std::swap instead of reinventing your own function.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of changes should fix it.

1. Use `while ( i < j )` instead of `while ( i != j )`.
2. Use `while (data[i] <= val)` instead of `while (data[i] < val)`

Here's my suggestion:

```
void partition(int data[], int size)
{
   int val = data[0];
   int i = 0, j = size - 1;
   while (i < j)
   {
      while (data[i] <= val)
         i++;
      while (data[j] > val)
         j--;
      swapInArray(data, i, j);
   }
}
```

**Update**

Couple of more changes are necessary.

1. Call `swapInArray` only if `i < j`.
2. Swap the pivot with the `j`-th element at the end, if necessary.

Updated function:

```
void partition(int data[], int size)
{
   int val = data[0];
   int i = 1, j = size - 1;//array indices
   while (i < j)
   {
      while (i < j && data[i] <= val)
         i++;

      while (data[j] > val)
         j--;

      if ( i < j )
         swapInArray(data, i, j);
   }
   if ( val > data[j] )
      swapInArray(data, 0, j);
}
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/5A3wTN.

Comment: still not working, giving the func int data[8] = { 5, 2, 10, 4, 1, 12, 5, 7 }; and it prints 5 2 5 4 12 1 10 7

Comment: That's because the two inner loops pass each other without checking; i points to 12 while j points to 1, and then those two get swapped. You need to stop increasing i and decreasing j once they meet. `while (i < j && data[i] <= val)` and `while (i < j && data[j] > val)` - and `if (i < j) swapInArray(...)`.

Comment: i didnt clearly understand what you mean. Can u show me wht changes in code to do?

Comment: I've updated my comment above. Also, I think you need to return the index of the first element of the second part of the partitioned array; otherwise you don't know how it was partitioned.

Comment: @RSahu unfortunately this needs a bit more thought. Your latest edited version doesn't work with a two-element array that is already sorted, such as {3, 8}. (Well, it "works" but in a useless way, because it partitions it into {8, 3} and {} - i.e. the first partition contains all the elements while the second partition contains zero elements.)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, thanks for pointing out the error. It's fixed now.